# Prove that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(c)=0$ if $ \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) =\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0 $.?

Tags: calculus, limits, maximum-principle

Suppose that $f$  is differentiable on $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) =\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0 $.
Prove that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(c)=0$ .

and can I extending this claim  to $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Use Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: Not one bit of the LaTeX rendered properly.

Comment: ok, thank you . I know it's one case of role theory but how i could prove it's truth ?

Comment: I will write down the solution if you show that you know the difference between Rolle's Theorem and role theory.

Comment: sorry , i mean Rolle's theorem

Comment: sorry, I am not writing an answer (even if I promised), someone else already did it better than I would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=-\pi/2$},\\[2ex]
f(\tan x) & \text{if $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$},\\[2ex]
0 & \text{if $x=-\pi/2$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $g$ is continuous on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and differentiable on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Since $g(-\pi/2)=g(\pi/2)$, Rolle's theorem applies and there exists $k\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ such that
$$
g'(k)=0.
$$
But $g'(x)=f'(\tan x)\cdot(1+\tan^2x)$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so
$$
f'(\tan k)=0
$$
and $c=\tan k$ is the number you're looking for.

In other words, you can apply Rolle's theorem also on $[-\infty,\infty]$.

It's not clear what generalization to $\mathbb{C}$ you have in mind.

Comment: ok, my goal is to use Rolle theoreme to show that the derivative of zeta function has no max or min values in the critical strip which implies that zeta function has a zeros in the critical strip .

Comment: I could always learn something ... I thought I knew that $(\tan x)'=\sec^2 x$ and that $1+\tan^2 x = \sec^2 x$, but it never occurred to me that $(\tan x)'=1+\tan^2 x$ :) So confusing ... it used to be the case that $(\tan x)'=\frac1{\cos^2 x}$

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko Just rewrite $\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\frac{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$ and split off the numerator. I usually avoid secants and cosecants. But the main point here is that the derivative of the tangent doesn't vanish on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, of course that is what I meant, writing it as $1+\tan^2 x$ makes is "more obvious" that it doesn't vanish.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is zero everywhere, then it's trivially true. Else WLOG $f(x)>0$ for some $x\in\mathbb R$. The limit conditions imply $f$ has a global maximum by [Weierstrass' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) on sufficiently large domain. The [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_%28stationary_points%29) then implies the derivative is $0$ there.

The complex case is false as is witnessed by $\dfrac{e^{it}}{t^2+1}$. (I'm assuming $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ is the generalization)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer , and according to your counter example Then we can't extending Rolle theoreme to $\mathbb{C}$ .Then in $\mathbb{C}$ how we could show that $f$ has  global a maximum values or no  ?

Comment: @user51189 What's a maximum of $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$? You can't reasonably compare complex numbers.

Comment: 2345215 , but you can compare complex numbers by module

Comment: @user51189 Yes, but that's a maximum of $|f|$, not of $f$. I still don't understand what do you want to extend, doesn't my example show you can't do it?

Comment: :look if we let $f$ be a complex function , $|f|=f$ if and only $f=0$ implies $f(s)=0 $ , for some  $ s$  , look the claim that i wrote $f(x)$ go to zero where $ x$ going to $\infty$  , is this applied under this claim and under the conditions writen below In complex numbers ensemble ( the comparaison has no sens in this case ) ?

Comment: @user51189 I don't understand you at all. What's a complex function anyway? $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ or $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$?